# ¿Cómo sé en qué posición aparece una subcadena dentro de una cadena?

Tags: python, string, substring

Tengo un programa el cual necesito que pida una frase y una palabra, si la palabra esta dentro de la frase la imprimira y indicara la posicion donde esta.

De momento tengo esto:

```
frase = input("Una frase: ")

palabra = input("Una palabra: ")

if palabra in frase:
    posicion = frase.find(palabra)
    print(posicion))
```

Me da 9 pero quiero que me de 7 para decir que empieza en el caracter 7 por ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás reinventando la rueda :)

Cuando haces [`str.find(substr)`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), ya te devuelve la posición en la que empieza la substring dentro de la string:

```
>>> 'holaquetal'.find('que')
4
>>> 'holaquetal'.find('XX')
-1
>>> 'holaquetal'.find('a')
3
>>> 'holaquetal'.find('a', 4)
8
>>> 'holaquetal'.find('a', 4, 5)
-1
```

Como ves, si le pasas un segundo parámetro busca *a partir* de esa posición. Y si le pasas un tercero, *hasta* esa posición. Por eso se define como `str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`.

En tu caso, simplemente devuelve `frase.find(palabra)` y ya está: dará -1 si no aparece *palabra* en *frase* y la posición en que lo hace si es que sí.

Comment: Lo he hecho pero me imprime el numero de strings contando la misma palabra, como input le digo: hola que tal bienvenido , y le pido la palabra 'tal' me da 9 pero quiero que me de 7 porque empieza en el caracter 7 no se si me explico

Comment: @qwerty pero la letra `t` de `tal` está en la posición 9.ª (porque se empieza por 0) de la cadena `hola que tal bienvenido`.

Comment: Ah vale creo que tambien los espacios cuentan gracias

Comment: @qwerty sí, exacto. Cada carácter cuenta, incluyendo los espacios.

Comment: si querés hacerlo sin contar los espacios como haría un humano, simplemente  eliminalos. "hola que tal bienvenido".replace(" ","").find("tal")